# Short the ground isolation of an isolated gate driver

Tags: ground, driver, isolation

I want to play with BLDC motor control and wanted to use the relatively new gate driver [UCC21520](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ucc21520) from TI. It is an isolated one. I'm wondering if for testing purposes there are any disadvantages if I connect the two grounds and so disable the isolation?
The main reason for me doing that is the measuring with my scope. If the grounds are isolated I have to measure one voltage differentially with two probes. If the grounds are connected, I can measure two voltages with two probes.

Comment: Just to be sure: The part has three areas, not two. If you have a high side MOSFET, say, at OUTA, don't short it. If you have a low-side MOSFET only, and don't need the isolation, why not use a more simple driver without the isolation?

Comment: Because I want to get familiar with BLDC controllers and want to use this isolated one in my later design. For getting in touch with BLDC controllers I have to measure around and that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can short VEE and VSS to perform coherent measurements on both sides of the IC.

The reinforced isolation barrier between interface and motor side is mainly for safety purposes since VDD could be about 550 V (not with this specific driver but in general electrical drives applications) and international norms require extra low voltages to be galvanically separated from non ELVs to be SELV or PELV if required.

Answer (score 0):

For test purposes with single ended 10:1 probes, you can certainly ground VssA and VssB for observing output waveforms in your unique layout and  setup. That just bypasses the internal cap. isolation for test purposes only, but prevents you from push pull drivers as intended.

Learn how to do differential probing with two probes and null adjust on the same square wave in A-B mode.

For best transient capture results , remove ground clip wire and probe tip and use test sockets for probe tipmand coil attachment accessory for probe ground barrel and support weight of probe. These test sockets would be like header sockets <1cm apart and next to circuit node.

[image]

Comment: no reason why You can't test the IC with common mode sources but obvious not use them that way as it would short out the low side switch.